# Unable to pass form data using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I am new to Angular.js and am trying to send form data to the server but I am getting an error for angular.js:13424 Error: [ng:areq]. I did try many answers available on Stack Overflow but I am not able to find the answer for my problem.

index.view.html (for register)

```
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" >    
       <input type="text" ng-model="fname" placeholder="Enter the name :"required >Fristname   
      <br> <br>
       button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn" ng-click=register()>Register </button>
   </div>
```

index.controller.js

```
   (function ()
      {
         angular
           .module('app')
           .controller('register.IndexController', function($scope,$http)
        {                
                $scope.register= function()
                {      
                   $http.post('http://localhost:9000/user/register', {firstName : $scope.fname}).success(function(response)
                    {        console.log($scope.fname);
                   })                                                                                       
                }  
        })

         });
```

index.html

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html ng-app="app">
      <head>
      <title>AngularJS JWT Authentication Example & Tutorial</title>
<!-- bootstrap css -->
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- application css -->
      <link href="app-content/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     </head>

<!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <nav class="cf" ng-include="'nav/index.view.html'" ng-controller="Main.IndexController"></nav>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Have you defined the module app somewhere else? if not then then you need to have this index.controller.js  `.module('app', [])`  If you have it defined elsewhere like that (with the square brackets) make sure you have it once and once only

Comment: it also looks like you are using a different controller name than the one you have declared: Main.IndexController vs register.IndexController...

Comment: @theTaoOfJS Yes I have defined it with square brackets with the respective dependencies and so at other controller files I have not included that part i.e. []

Comment: @NeilHibbert In the router part I have defined the controller for different pages for ex: .state('register', {
                url: '/register',
                templateUrl: 'register/index.view.html',
                controller: 'register.IndexController'

Comment: ok, but where is the 'Main' object declared? is it in a parent $scope somewhere? because it doesn't look like your <nav ng-controller="Main.IndexController" /> element is attached to an actual controller...

Comment: I have given all the links for the respective controller files. I have follwed this tutorial http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/04/05/angularjs-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Comment: @HebleV: Please replace ng-controller="Main.IndexController" with ng-controller="register.IndexController". It should work. Please try once.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using the wrong controller identifier while processing your request.

You have named your controller as **register.IndexController**, but from the html , you are trying to access it as **Main.IndexController**.

Please check whether changing the html controller idenentifier solves your problem.

If you plan on using nested controllers, you can do that also. But the scope has to be identified correctly whichever controller you are using.

Comment: I have used nested controllers and it is working for different pages except for this registration part.